# How to make an image fully flexible in terms of display size?

Tags: html, css

forgive me if my question is too newbie.

So I have an image, and it is not that big.

So what I want is:

1. If the size (width) of its container is bigger, then display the image as its original size
2. If the width of its container becomes smaller, like user narrow down the browser, then also automatically make the image smaller.

The reason for the point 1 is that since the image's size might be smaller than the container normally (depending on how the user adjusts the browser), I don't want the image (jpg) to be stretched to bigger and that would make the image blur.

Then I used the following css:

```
{
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}
```

The effect is not what I want:

1. If img's container is bigger, it is fine:

[image]

2. But if I narrow down the container (browser):

[image]

You can see that the image's size stays the same, but partially hidden or covered.

How can I really achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the CSS to:

```
width:100%
max-width:500px;
```

This is in case the image is originally 500px wide.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/eff76s2u/

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if I don't know the original size? it can be any image and i can't hard code the original size info

Comment: hmm... it seems `width:auto; max-width:100%;` will do the trick